# PHP Async Receiver only without request first

Tags: php, mysql, asynchronous, soap, wsdl

I'm in the situation that I have a company sending the response message back via xml as an async to my feedbackurl as they put it a ?wsdl

Im stuck as I cant see anywhere that explains or an example how to capture the response when they only hit my feedback url with a GET.

if anyone has any ideas how to capture the full header body of what they are doing with a GET, I have captured the get headers into mysql as they hit it but nothing in there saying content length etc and last header is authorization: which there isn't one its ip whitelist.

Also a question is Async response delivered as a GET or have they misconfigured something and it should be a POST.

example of what it does so far

code is used to curl request to a ?wsdl url that then returns a response of pending

from 30 seconds to 2 hours a response should come back and be sent to a totally different ?wsdl on my side but because there is no request waiting for a response, this is where im stuck.

The ultimate aim is to Get the XML response as a variable and if the response is there once dealt with send a response.

I have this working if it was a curl that sent a request but if its only sending a response im confused of how to capture just the response.

Part from the API Document I have removed the real company domain.

"The Feedback Receiver web service WSDL must be striclty identical to the
WSDL detailed at the end of this section, including Target Namespace, Port
name and Service name).
Ports used for the FeedbackReceiver URL must be standard: 443 (recommended),
80, 8443, 8080."

page 119 in the pdf below wouldn't let me put the code in without it giving code errors.

Comment: You can get headers from any type of request (GET, POST, DELETE etc). You can also get the querystring variables from the URL from any type of request. But yes, by convention GET requests don't contain a body. You didn't actually show an example of the request or the data you want to get from it precisely though, so it's a bit difficult to be sure what's going on as your terminology is a bit woolly in some places.

Comment: I will add the part of there api document in a minute or so so you can see what it talks about see if it sheds light on what I would be expecting to see. thank you

Comment: Ok thanks. If they are sending a GET with `?wsdl` at the end it sounds like maybe they are just requesting your WSDL file. That's always the first step in a SOAP request. Then after that you should expect another request - hopefully a POST - to the main URL which will contain the XML data they are sending you.

Answer (score 0):

ADyson gave me the hint. all working with nusoap and wsdl file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).